# Firebase Realtime Database - Auto Generate Primary Key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing some data to a Firebase Realtime Database.

User Class

```
data class User(
    @Exclude var userId: String? = "",
    var username: String? = "",
    var email: String? = ""
)
```

Write Function

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        bt_register_button.setOnClickListener {
            val username = et_register_username.text.toString()
            val email = et_register_email.text.toString()

            writeNewUser("1", username, email)
        }

    }

    private fun writeNewUser(userId: String, username: String, email: String?) {
        val user = User(username, email)
        mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user)
    }

}
```

Using the above, I can create a User record with a preset Id of 1:

```
users
     1
          email: "bill@gmail.com"
          username: "bill"
```

I obviously want the Id to be generated automatically upon creation.

I am aware of the push() function but I'm not sure how to implement it.

**Edit 1**

Thank you, the User key is now being set as the User UID (from Authentication):

```
    private fun writeNewUser(name: String, email: String?) {
        val user = User(name, email)
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).setValue(user)
    }
```

[image: Authentication + Write Database Result]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) instead of `child(userId)`:

```
mDatabase.child("users").push().setValue(user)
```

Comment: If you're **also** using Firebase Authentication, please use `mDatabase.child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user)` instead. This stores the users under their UID, which makes looking them up a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Doug, the first solution worked perfectly. I am actually using Firebase Authentication so I'll now attempt to use the Uid instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code to create auto generated key for firebase realtime database

**Using push()**

```
myRef.child(APP_TABLE).child(USER_TABLE).push().setValue(detail)
```

**Using Authentication Current UUID  key**

```
myRef.child(APP_TABLE).child(USER_TABLE).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(detail)
```